# Add custom textures and vertex attributes

Tags: scripting

I'm a new user of Blender, but I have 10 years experience of 3d development (mainly C++/OpenGL, but I know Python pretty well).

Now I plan to use Blender as a replacement tool for the "good old ones we made by hand" in my company. These tools are made to prepare 3D model before importing them in our "scientific rendering and computation" softwares.

Blender offers all the geometry edition tools we need, but we also need specific data, such as surface temperatures, coverages maps, algorithms parameters in vertex attributes...

So here is my question :

Is there any built-in way in blender to add and edit a texture in a specific "OpenGL" format (for example, a single channel 32 bits float texture) and mark it as "custom texture 1" or "custom texture 2"... ?

Or should I make an add-on for this ?

The same for vertex attributes : is there any built-in way in blender to add and edit a custom vertex attribute or should I make an add-on for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: see the [bmesh module](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bmesh.types.html#custom-data-layer-access) it may have what you need

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I see the bmesh module lets you add values via Python, but is there a way to do it via the GUI?

Comment: One option would be to paint one or more vertex color layers or UV sets. Exporting to glTF (and perhaps other formats) will preserve the vertex colors and each UV set as separate attributes.