# Use custom vertex attribute in Attribute node (shader network)

Tags: python, scripting, shaders, shader-nodes

I was reading this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/what-can-you-call-from-the-attribute-node) and this [one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27873/add-custom-textures-and-vertex-attributes) :

Other than copy new data to specific "known" vertex attribute like "Color" for example.

There is way to read custom vertex attributes in the Attribute node \ shader network 
shader script  ?

Comment: ATM, you can read any attribute defined / redefined within Geometry Nodes.. would that do?

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you for the reply,
I`m going to use same vertex weights for shape key and shader mix as part of automated process. can I incorporate and control the geometry nodes graph using python ?
It might help...

Wrote this question while ago:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231304/access-and-using-geometry-nodes-as-functions-in-python

Comment: Well, the shader can read  vertex weights via GeoNodes, (that would be in the modifier/shader  combo, a fixed pipeline). If you need the plumbing to be automated via Python, I'm not sure whether the API reaches GeoNodes yet. Maybe hold out for a Pythonista.

Answer (score 2):

This code example and related image demonstrate creation of new vertex
attributes and using them in the shader network.

- I was not able to create string based attribute
- Its important to use cycles to easily see the results
  when using vertex attribute values higher than 1.0

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy import data as data, context as context
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh
import numpy as np

#clean objects in scene
for object in data.objects :
    if object.type == 'MESH':
        data.objects.remove(object, do_unlink=True)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
obj_a = data.objects["Cube"]
obj_a.name = "A"

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
obj_b = data.objects["Cube"]
obj_b.name = "B"
obj_b.hide_viewport = True

a_mesh = obj_a.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(a_mesh)


# Create a new vertex attributes
# color: 0-1 value 4 element float (it will clamp if > 1)
# float_color: non normalzied 4 elemnet vector
# float: single float
# vector_float: non normalized 3 element vector
# string :was not able to create string vertex attribute

knafeh_color = bm.loops.layers.color.new("knafeh_color")
malabi_color_float = bm.loops.layers.float_color.new("malabi_color_float")
falafel_float = bm.loops.layers.float.new("falafel_float")
salad_vector_float = bm.loops.layers.float_vector.new("salad_vector_float")
baklava_str = bm.loops.layers.string.new("baklava_str")


bm_faces = bm.faces
for bm_face in bm_faces:
    face_loops = bm_face.loops
    for bm_loop in face_loops:

        # Assign color to vertex.
        bm_loop[knafeh_color] = [0.9,0.5,0,1]
        bm_loop[malabi_color_float] = [7,0.1,9999,1]
        bm_loop[salad_vector_float] = [1,1,0]
        bm_loop[falafel_float] = 0.1
        

        
bm.to_mesh(a_mesh)
bm.free()
```